# Rest Api Design: Using resource path with alias as a sub-resource

Tags: rest, get, api-design

I build a rest api and I was wondering if it's possible to use an adjective in the resource path like

```
GET /tickets/recently_closed

GET /tickets/filtered
```

To Retrieve recently closed tickets or filtered tickets otherwise how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> if it's possible to use an adjective in the resource path

Yes, of course.  REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use, and the machines are perfectly happy to download resources regardless of the spelling conventions used.

For example:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/filtered

> otherwise how to do that

Remembering please that the spellings you proposed above are *fine*...

These look like "reports".  So go talk to your local domain experts and find out what the name of each report is, and use the name of the report as the inspiration for identifying the resource.